# Is there any way to reliably get the plain text from a .doc file using php?

Tags: php, ms-word, doc

The things I've tried:

**read_doc():**

```
private function read_doc() {
$fileHandle = fopen($this->filename, "r");
$line = @fread($fileHandle, filesize($this->filename));   
$lines = explode(chr(0x0D),$line);
$outtext = "";
foreach($lines as $thisline)
  {
    $pos = strpos($thisline, chr(0x00));
    if (($pos !== FALSE)||(strlen($thisline)==0))
      {
      } else {
        $outtext .= $thisline." ";
      }
  }
 $outtext = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\n\r\t@\/\_\(\)]/","",$outtext);
return $outtext;}
```

**getRawWordText():**

```
function getRawWordText($filename) {
if(file_exists($filename)) {
    if(($fh = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== false ) {
        $headers = fread($fh, 0xA00);
        $n1 = ( ord($headers[0x21C]) - 1 );// 1 = (ord(n)*1) ; Document has from 0 to 255 characters
        $n2 = ( ( ord($headers[0x21D]) - 8 ) * 256 );// 1 = ((ord(n)-8)*256) ; Document has from 256 to 63743 characters
        $n3 = ( ( ord($headers[0x21E]) * 256 ) * 256 );// 1 = ((ord(n)*256)*256) ; Document has from 63744 to 16775423 characters
        $n4 = ( ( ( ord($headers[0x21F]) * 256 ) * 256 ) * 256 );// 1 = (((ord(n)*256)*256)*256) ; Document has from 16775424 to 4294965504 characters
        $textLength = ($n1 + $n2 + $n3 + $n4);// Total length of text in the document
        $extracted_plaintext = fread($fh, $textLength);
        $extracted_plaintext = mb_convert_encoding($extracted_plaintext,'UTF-8');
         // if you want to see your paragraphs in a new line, do this
         // return nl2br($extracted_plaintext);
         return ($extracted_plaintext);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} else {
    return false;
}  }
```

**DocCounter:** https://github.com/joeblurton/doccounter

**DocumentParser:** https://github.com/LukeMadhanga/PHPDocumentParser

**Filetotext:** 
https://www.phpclasses.org/package/8908-PHP-Convert-DOCX-DOC-PDF-to-plain-text.html#information 
https://gist.github.com/HadoDokis/bb7b4a7763a56eba2c5c

**PhpWord:** https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

And a couple other functions I can't recall at the moment.

The goal of the project is to extract the text and count the number of **characters** without whitespace.

The criteria is that the given solution should have a maximum error margin of **10%** when compared to the MS Word character count.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't those libraries work?

Comment: Depends on if you're decoding binary DOCs or XML-variants. Another common tool, btw: `antiword`.

Comment: @Barmar The average character difference in the source .doc file and the extracted plain text is well over 100% - meaning: in most of the tests they returned double and over the double amount of characters. Left over from formatting, tables etc.

Comment: They may be multi-byte charaters, make sure you're counting characters, not bytes.

Comment: @mario Already tried antiword, same problem as the others. The only thing that comes even close is LibreOffice, so that is what I'll use if there is no other way.

Comment: @Barmar I convert them to a .txt file and process that with a string processor while observing the output. I'm 100% counting characters.

Comment: Have you noticed any pattern to what characters are missing?

Comment: Open the document, save it as a plain text file, then read that. Do note that headers & footers will be placed after the body text when you do this.

Comment: @macropod If you know a way to do that accurately with php, please tell me

Comment: @Barmar Not really. My guess is it's mostly formatting that's left in the result, but then again the amount of plus characters depends on which method I use. There are even some documents that come out of the process with less text than the original.